# Accessing value from a function

Tags: php, json

I found a function that returns some data from an API that I need:

**class.php**

```
class APIfunc {
    private function secret_key(){
        return $secret_key = '**KEY**';
    }

    public function request($engine, $prompt, $max_tokens){

        $request_body = [
            "prompt" => $prompt,
            "max_tokens" => $max_tokens,
        ];

        $postfields = json_encode($request_body);
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://apidomain.com/engines/" . $engine,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: ' . $this->secret_key()
            ],
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    }
}
```

and the use is as following:

```
require_once 'class.php';
$apidata = New APIfunc();
$response = $apidata->request("dav", "This is a test", 1);
```

The result I'm getting looks like this:

```
{"id": "cmpl-3N4Hwl3G", "object": "text_completion", "created": 1626627040, "model": "dav:2020-05-03", "choices": [{"text": " of", "index": 0, "logprobs": null, "finish_reason": "length"}]}
```

All I need is the "text" value, but I'm not sure how to access it. I've tried:

```
echo json_decode($response)->choices[0]->text;
```

and even

```
$data = explode( ',', $response);
```

But to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: Your request function doesn't return anything, it simply echoes the result and then stops. So in `$response = $apidata->request`, $response will always be empty unless you change the request function to return the response from the curl request

Comment: I think you're right. It comes from echo $response; What needs to be changed?

Comment: Just change it to `return $response;` instead. If you're not sure how functions work to the point you have to ask about creating a return value, then you would probably benefit from taking some introductory tutorials online.

Comment: Fixed it! It never even dawned to examine closely the function I found and was using. Spent time tweaking my own code... Thanks!